# AutoHotkey text-conditioned Tab to Right Arrow

Tags: tabs, notepad++, autohotkey

I try to have Tab send Right when caret is before " or ' or ) or ] or }... with an AutoHotkey script.

1) How can I detect these characters without messing with the AHK conditional code?
2) I managed to get Tab sending Right when before a random character but it doesn't send Tab when the condition is not true.

Can you help me please ? I feel I am not far from the expected behavior.

Here is my code:

```
; Notepad++ | Tab = right arrow if before " or ' or ) or ] or }
GetCaretText()
{
ClipboardToRestore := ClipboardAll
Clipboard = 
Send +{right 1}
Send ^c
ClipWait
Send {left 1}
CaretText := Clipboard
Clipboard := ClipboardToRestore
return CaretText
}
Tab::
if (GetCaretText() = "" or GetCaretText() = "" or GetCaretText() = "" or GetCaretText() = "" or GetCaretText() = "")
    Send {right}
else
    Send {tab}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

**This makes <kbd>TAB</kbd> skip past these characters `" ' ) ] }` instead of sending a tab**

```
; This configures #If statements to match anywhere in title
SetTitleMatchMode 2

#IfWinActive - Notepad++
  $Tab::onTab()
#IfWinActive

onTab()
{
  ClipboardToRestore := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard =
  send +{right}^c
  clipwait 0.1
  CaretText := Clipboard
  Clipboard := ClipboardToRestore
  if (!CaretText)
    send {tab}
  else if (instr( """')]}", CaretText))
    send +{left}{right}
  else
    send +{left}{tab}
}
```

**This is an alternative version that doesn't consume <kbd>TAB</kbd>**

```
~Tab::onTab()

onTab()
{
  ClipboardToRestore := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard =
  send {left}+{right 2}^c
  ClipWait
  CaretText := Clipboard
  Clipboard := ClipboardToRestore
  if (strlen(CaretText) == 1)
    send +{left}{right}
  else if (instr( """')]}", substr(CaretText, 2)))
    send +{left}{delete}{right}
  else
    send +{left 2}{right}
}
```

**Notes:**

- The [modifier symbol `~`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) passes through the keypress (in this case <kbd>TAB</kbd>)
- [`instr(haystack, needle)`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InStr.htm) tests if the string `needle` is in `haystack`
- Quotation marks in string literals are [escaped](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm) by doubling the quotation mark, i.e., `a:=""""` sets `a` to `"`
- The code attempts to capture two characters -- the tab that was just pressed and the next character.  If the caret was at the end of the buffer, only the tab will be captured, and then `send {right}` is used to skip the tab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
It works, but when I press Tab in an empty line of another document than the script itself, the script doesn't work anymore, the Tab key is disabled, I have to reload the script. Any idea what causes this behavior?

Comment: Mh, this one doesn't work "at all" and does weird things ^^ Maybe a combination of both versions would do the job (the first one was almost ok)

Comment: Thank you but is it a good approach to try to adress each case "manually"? The new code has this unexpected behavior for example: it messes up with my snippets — my snippet fired with "if + tab" should send "if (|){}" but sends "if if )|{}" — I think we should rebase from the first script. By the way I am in Notepad++ and it's okay if the code works only in there.

Comment: I have tested the above code in notepad, gvim, MSWord and Notepad++ and it works correctly. I cannot reproduce your problem. Notepad++ doesn't have built-in snippets support AFAIK. Are you using a plugin that does something when you type "if" and then the TAB key?

Comment: Yes I use FingerText plugin for snippets

Comment: I updated my answer to work with FingerText. I also restricted the hotkey to Notepad++ windows